# Constructor invocation issue

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++builder

In this code when try to create dobj4 got compiler error

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class mod;
class  name {
    friend mod;
    public:
            name(const char* n) {
                    cout << "1 arg constructor for name\n";
            }
            name() {
                    cout << "no arg constructor for name\n";
            }
            name(const char* n, int i ){
                    cout << "2 arg constructor for name\n";
            }
      };

class mod {
    public:
    mod() {
            cout << "base class constructor invoked\n";
    }
};

struct derived : mod {

    derived(name) {
            cout << "derived constructor invoked\n";
    }
 };

int main() {
    name nobj;
    derived dobj(nobj);

    name nobj1("hello");
    derived dobj1(nobj1);

    derived dobj2("Hi");

    name nobj2("yo", 2);
    derived dobj3(nobj2);

 //      derived dobj4("go", 4);

    return 0;
}
```

Need to understand how when pass strings invoke constructor for name in case of `dobj2` but in case of `dobj4` it is causing error.
How to correct this issue?

Comment: Constructors aren't inherited automatically.

Comment: The derived doesn't have constructor which will accept two parameters. Add a constructor in derived as derived(const char *n, int n) { // impelmentation }. It should work.

Comment: I suspect that you've misunderstood how the implicit conversion of arguments works. Read some more about it in your favourite C++ book.

Comment: Yes new to c++ ,  I am trying to understand how that conversion takes place dobj2 but not in dobj4, Thanks for support

Comment: @ashkun I think you need to clarify your question. It took some time to understand your problem even with the comment from molbdnilo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rule for converting constructors varies in `C++03` and `C++11`.

In `C++03`: Constructors with only one argument, or in case of more than one arguments have rest of the arguments with a *default value* are implicitly convertible.

Example:

```
name(const char* n) {}
name(int n, int i = 0) {} // i has a default value
```

In `C++11`: All the cases defined in `C++03` above along with constructors with more than one argument. But such constructor calls needs to be *brace-initialized*.

Example:

```
derived dobj4({"go", 4}); // call to name(const char* n, int i) is brace-initialized
```

Needless to say, if the constructor is declared `explicit`, it won't be converting.

Comment: I think you mean to say that the constructor is a "converting constructor" if it meets those parameter conditions. But that is not really anything to do with the problem, it is just terminology

Comment: Yeah that one doesn't have the default parameter. Still not sure what you're trying to say.

Comment: With C++11 flag, it should be constructed with brace-initialization even though there are more than one parameters with no default values except the first. The first line in my example compiles (with `({})`), the second with only `{}` does not.

Comment: Oh I see. But the default parameter in your code above makes the constructors potentially ambiguous. That distracted me.

Comment: Ah. Bad example on my part. Rectified it.

Comment: Dear downvoter, is something wrong with my approach?

Answer (score 1):

I feel like your question could have a lot shorter and easier to understand sample code: (I also fixed to make it compilable)

I left the derived name even if the inheritance has no relevance here and I have removed it as not important

```
#include<iostream>
class  name {
public:
    name() {
        std::cout << "no arg constructor for name\n";
    }
    name(const char* n) {
        std::cout << "1 arg(" << n <<") constructor for name\n";
    }
    name(const char* n, int i ) {
        std::cout << "2 arg(" << n << ',' << i <<") constructor for name\n";
    }
};
struct derived {

    derived(const name& n ) {
        std::cout << "derived name constructor invoked\n";
        (void)n;
    }
};

int main() {

    name nobj;
    derived dobj(nobj);

    derived dobj2("Hi");

    derived dobj4({"go", 4}); //see the initialization list instead of 2 parameters passing

    return 0;
}
```